# Can we write energy band of square lattice with vertical magnetic field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, electronic-band-theory, lattice-model, tight-binding

I am interested in a square lattice with the vertical magnetic field. Without a magnetic field, we can know the energy dispersion of the square lattice easily. But, how about in case of with magnetic field? My theory shown below is correct or not?

**Without magnetic field**

We use tight-binding approximation. We consider only 2Pz orbitals and up to the nearest hopping integral t. Of course, t is a real number. In this case, Hamiltonian matrix is one dimenstional since number of atoms in the unit cell of this system is only one and given by 
$$
H(k_x,k_y) = te^{ik_xa}+te^{-ik_xa}+te^{ik_ya}+te^{-ik_ya} \\
=2t \cos{k_xa}+ 2t \cos{k_y a},
$$

where a is lattice constant. And we can define wave vector $\vec{k}=(k_x,k_y)$ because system has periodic boundary condition. 
Right figure is energy dispersion of this system.

[image]

**With magnetic field**

We consider the square lattice with the vertical magnetic field $\vec{B}=(0,0,B)$. We define the vector potential $\vec{A}=(0,Bx,0)$. In this system, transfer integral becomes complex number because of Peierls phase. You know that when we consider magnetic field transfer integral t become 
$${\rm texp}[i\int_C \vec{A} \cdot d{\vec r}].$$ 
C is the path of the hopping. In this system, hopping integral of x-direction does not change because $${\rm exp}[(0,Bx,0)\cdot(1,0,0)]=1.$$

But hopping integral of y-direction change and it depends on the x position. This is why the number of atoms in a unit cell becomes N. The red line means unit-cell of this system in the figure. Now, we consider periodic boundary condition in x and y-direction. So,

\begin{eqnarray}
te^{i(N+1)Ba}=te^{iBa}.
\end{eqnarray}

We can understand $B$ should be satisfied with

$$
B=\frac{2n \pi}{Na}
$$

where n is integer.

[image]

So I made the hamiltonian matrix in case of $N=4$. 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2t\cos{(Ba+k_ya)} & te^{ik_xa} & 0 & te^{-ik_xa}\\
te^{-ik_xa} & 2t\cos{(2Ba+k_ya)} & te^{ik_xa} & 0\\
0 & te^{-ik_xa} & 2t\cos{(3Ba+k_ya)} & te^{ik_xa}\\
te^{ik_xa} & 0 & te^{-ik_xa} & 2t\cos{(4Ba+k_ya)}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

And according to the Mathematica8, we can know the Eigenvalues analytically, and I plotted it for t=1,a=1 and n=1. So this is energy dispersion of square lattice with magnetic field. Is this correct??

[image]

**Edit**

According to the Mathematica8, when B=0, eigenvalues of the 4-dimensional Hamiltonian are
$$
-2t\cos{k_xa}+2t\cos{k_ya}, \\
2t\cos{k_xa}+2t\cos{k_ya},\\
2t\cos{k_xa}-2t|\sin{k_ya}|,\\
2t\cos{k_xa}+2t|\sin{k_ya}|.
$$

It is very strange. Why it is not same as the result of the previous section "Without magnetic field"

I found [this document](https://www.google.co.jp/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjjpN-Fwv7WAhWCgbwKHd_8BG0QFghHMAc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9783319258270-c2.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-1544917-p177762451&usg=AOvVaw01MN5zR9sMSv6Pvy1HwUFD). Would you see Fig.2.6? I feel this figure is same as mine.

Comment: The problem you're describing is known as [Hofstadter's butterfly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter%27s_butterfly), due to the butterfly appearance of the fractal spectrum it generates.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you enlarge the unit cell in $x$ direction, you apply the magnetic periodic boundary condition in both $x$ and $y$. On the other hand, when you choose the magnetic unit cells to be $N$ times larger than the lattice ones, your Brillouin zone also shrinks $N$ times. Hence, the energy spectrum is usually depicted with respect to magnetic momenta.

Reference: W. Cai and G. Galli, "*Ab Initio* Calculations in a Uniform Magnetic Field Using Periodic Supercells", [*Phys. Rev. Lett.* **92**, 186402 (2004)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.92.186402).